# How to add some action after user logs in symfony 2.1 application

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a symfony 2.1 application. I followed the tutorial on creating login system from symfony 2.1 documentation. My table structure for user is like this:

```
   users
    -id
    -username
    -email
    -password
    -last_login_date
```

What I want to do is update last_login_date for that user when the user logs in. Also update the last_login_date when the user had enabled remember me option.
How can I do this in symfony 2.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to listen to the **security.interactive_login** event (you can read more about events [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html).

Also, check **FOSUserBundle**, it implements a [LastLoginListener](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/EventListener/LastLoginListener.php) which is configured [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/security.xml#L13)